# fir2 from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to convert the fir2 filter to python by using the spicy.signal.firwin2 function however the following error is returned :

```
from scipy import signal as sigs
orderFIR = 4096
# WdBCor is a numpy array with 22050 values 
outMidFIR = sigs.firwin2(orderFIR+1,range(0,FS/2,1),10**(WdB_cor / 20))
```

The error is :

{ValueError}freq must start with 0 and end with `nye`.

Can anyone explain what the problem is? Or should I be using another function to perform the same fir2 filter like Matlab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation of [`fir2win`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin2.html) very carefully.  For the second parameter, `freq`, it says:

> `freq` : `array_like`, 1D
>
> The frequency sampling points. Typically 0.0 to 1.0 with 1.0 being Nyquist. The Nyquist frequency can be redefined with the argument `nyq`. The values in `freq` must be nondecreasing. A value can be repeated once to implement a discontinuity. The first value in `freq` must be 0, and the last value must be `nyq`.

As such, you first need to provide an additional parameter called `nyq` that redefines the Nyquist frequency as it currently assumes 1.0 is Nyquist.  Simply put, you would do `nyq=FS/2` in this case.  Secondly, `range` does **not** include the ending point and this function requires that you specify the Nyquist frequency as the last element in the array.  As such, you're better off using [`numpy.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) for that which will include both the starting and ending point.

Therefore, you would do this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as sigs

orderFIR = 4096
num_points = len(Wdb_cor) # Get total number of points
outMidFIR = sigs.firwin2(orderFIR+1,np.linspace(0,FS/2,num_points),10**(WdB_cor/20), nyq=FS/2)
```